# How to validate an RSA cert in perl

Tags: perl, openssl, rsa, x509

How do you validate an cert given a root cert that signed it?  I've got this far:

```perl
 $root_x509 = Crypt::OpenSSL::X509->new_from_string($root_key_data, FORMAT_ASN1);
 $root_key = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_public_key($x509->pubkey());  

 $other_x509 = Crypt::OpenSSL::X509->new_from_string($other_key_data, FORMAT_ASN1);
 $other_key = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_public_key($x509->pubkey());
```

Ok, then what? I'm not seeing an obvious `$root_key->verify_certificate($other_x509)`;  Is Crypt::OpenSSL::VerifyX509 the only/best answer? That module is being problematic to compile and install, but I'll continue in that vein if it's the way to go. But I feel like I'm missing something.

It looks like python, for example, has an obvious API an equivalent to which I'm not seeing in any of the OpenSSL perl libraries:

```python
trusted_store = X509Store()
trusted_store.add_cert(trusted_root)

try:
  X509StoreContext(trusted_store, itunes_cert).verify_certificate()
except X509StoreContextError as e:
  print("iTunes certificate invalid")
```

Comment: Take a look at http://search.cpan.org/~chrisa/Crypt-OpenSSL-VerifyX509-0.10/VerifyX509.pm

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking at that. The unit tests don't pass, they're not failing in obvious ways, and they fail differently on different platforms (Centos 6, Centos 7, MacOS).

Comment: The source code of Crypt::OpenSSL::VerifyX509 looks pretty simple. Can you give more info about failing?

Answer (score 0):

After extensive research, the closest thing to a complete solution besides Crypt::OpenSSL::VerifyX509 (see above) is Net::SSLeay, which has a whole bunch of low-level bindings to openssl. They recently added these:

```
1.83 2018-01-06
    X509_STORE_CTX_new and X509_verify_cert
```

but the documentation is sparse, and I wasn't able to get past related segfaults.

Instead I validated the cert chain by hand:

1. use Convert::ASN1 to re-encode the tbsCertificate data I had decoded
   in my PKCS#7 file ("tbs" is "to-be-signed")
2. get the signature from the PCKS#7 data
3. get the subjectPublicKeyInfo.subjectPublic Key from the cert that signed this cert
4. feed that to $signer_key = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_public_key($signer_key_pem);
5. and then do $signer_key->verify($cert_as_signed, $signature)

and repeat for each cert in the chain.

Checking validity dates and extension capabilities on each cert is part of all that.